# C++ debugger not going into method

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, debugging

So I set a break point at the line Collide(0,1); and I try to step into the method but it wont go in there. Any ideas why?

```
Collide(0,1);
if(PosX<(screen->h-40))
{
    if(LevelOne[screenCamera.ScreenOffsetX][screenCamera.ScreenOffsetY+1] == 0) //Collision
    {
        screenCamera.SavePreviousOffests();
        screenCamera.ScreenOffsetY += 1;
        if(screenCamera.ScreenOffsetY > 30 ||
           screenCamera.ScreenOffsetY < 10 ||
           screenCamera.PreviosScreenOffsetY == 9)
        {
            Move(0, 40);
        }
    }
}

bool Hero::Collide(int xMovement, int yMovement)
{
    int nextPositionContents = LevelOne[PosX/40 + xMovement][PosY/40 + yMovement];
    if(nextPositionContents == 11) //blue key
    {
        //LevelOne[PosX/40 + xMovement][PosY/40+ yMovement] == 0;
        HasBlueKey = true;
    }
    if(nextPositionContents == 10 && HasBlueKey)//blue door
    {
        //LevelOne[PosX/40+ xMovement][PosY/40+ yMovement] == 0;
        HasBlueKey = false;
    }
    nextPositionContents = 0;

    return false;
}
```

Comment: Has it been inlined? what does the disassembly look like?

Comment: Im not sure what you mean by either of those things. Please elaborate. This is all within a class called hero

Comment: Do you compile with optimization? If so, don't.

Comment: Inlining is where the compiler takes the contents of the function you are calling and just inserts it into the current function, allowing it to optimise the code. Looking at the disassembly would tell you what's going on, and should be an option in your debugger.

Comment: Compile without optimization? Isnt that a bad idea?

Comment: It's a bad idea for a release build you want to be fast. It's a good idea if you want to debug your code.

Comment: No, for debugging, it's important to disable optimization. Optimization makes it harder for the debugger to trace the code (see what @JasonD said).

Comment: Ok Great. Can I Get that in answer form and tell me how to disable this?

Comment: beside being inlined, you could be calling a derived virtual function that ignores it's base. but that's just another guess, since the class declaration is not provided

Comment: @Jonathan O to disable it we need to know the compiler you are using

Comment: This is in Visual studio 2010

Comment: In Visual Studio, the "debug" build, which is there by default, should not have optimisations enabled (unless you've specifically done so). You can see the disassembly by right-clicking on the source (while in the debugger, at point where you're trying to step) and selecting "Go To Disassembly". You should be able to see if it's calling a function (and you can also single-step the debugging through the asm, even if it's inlined).